# Open activity from notification seems to destroy callstack

Tags: android, push-notification

I have an activity which can be opened from a notification which is sent by a server, this also can be opened from other activity on the app, but there is an issue. When an activity is opened from a notification and if the user try to go back the app goes to background and next time it's opened it will show the login(main) activity instead the last in the call stack, it will do that both if the app is active or in background, and any error message is shown nor the debug process stops.

This is my notification code

```
void client(Bundle bundle){
        String title = bundle.getString("title");
        String message = bundle.getString("message");
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        seticon(builder);
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentText(message);
        if(message.length()>25){
            builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(message));
        }

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Client_form.class);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(Cliente_form.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            resultPendingIntent=
                    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                            0,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );
        }
        builder.addAction(R.drawable.common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light,"Open",resultPendingIntent);
        builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_mail_outline_black_24dp,"Test",null);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(id_notifi++, builder.build());

        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        r.play();
 }
```

the expected behavior is that if the activity opens on top of the call stack and when back is pressed should return to the previous activity.

Any idea of why this is happening or how to make it work as expected?

Comment: You ever find a solution to this issue? Having the same problem!

Comment: @GeordieWicks sorry but no, to this day we still didn't implement the notification system.

Comment: I found this issue with my code, it had to do with the way I implemented the stackbuilder.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue, and it had to do with my implementation of the StackBuilder, in some configurations, it automatically calls the onDestroy method of the activity that originally called the notification or the notifications broadcast receiver.

Try removing the Stackbuilder completely, and if that fixes the issue, you can hunt down the exact problem, mine had to do with adding the wrong class.

Comment: Yes sir, replaced TaskStackBuilder with PendingIntent.getActivity() and it solved the problem